# Magento 2 module development incremental updates

Tags: magento2

I am new to Magento, I am trying to create a custom module.
After installing it locally, enable it from command line, run setup and compile, I can use it, although whenever I modify/update one of the php files, the changes are not reflected, although I have set magento into developer mode, disabled all caches from Admin cache management.
I am using php 7.0, apache 2.4.
Thanks

Comment: Are you using any other third party cache mechanism like Redis ?

Comment: you should probably specify the name and path of the file and the url you are hitting to see the reflection

Comment: No, I am not using any custom ache mechanism, just normal magento2 installation over php 7 apache 2.4

Comment: I mean whenever I enable a module, I have to run the setup, then the setup asks for running setup:di:compile, so I am not sure if it has something to do with re-compile only the changed php files or not